# Getting Error in config.txt file of NetSim Simulator

Tags: networking, network-programming, simulation

When I open NetSim's Config.txt file after Simulation I get the following error:

```
Error in config file ---
1) Unknown xml tag "UPDATE_TIMER" in line number 166.
Tag path: TETCOS_NETSIM/NETWORK_CONFIGURATION/DEVICE_CONFIGURATION/DEVICE
[3] /LAYER [2]/ROUTING_PROTOCOL/PROTOCOL_PROPERTY
```

However, Simulation runs `Successfully`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the missing parameters in the Configuration file which are mentioned in the "ConfigLog.txt". **Since, NetSim will crash if all the required parameters are not configured, NetSim addresses this issue by enabling default values where ever required**. Error produced in the "ConfigLog.txt" because the value for the "UPDATE_TIMER" for "ROUTING_PROTOCOL" is not specified in the Configuration file. In order to obtain accurate metrics for the desired scenario you need to update your Configuration.xml file.